# Makefile for Go

Tags: go, makefile

I have added a new Go test stub into my project's test tools repo in a folder called "newTest" which contains "newTest.go, util.go and util_test.go". In the parent directory there is a makefile that automates the building of all test tools and then dockerize them. There already exists a separate Go test stub executable that gets built (existingTest) in the test tools repo. This is the current makefile (redacted):

```
// Set up and do other stuff  
existingTest:
    env GOPATH=${PWD}/../external_vendor go build existingTest.go

docker: 
    @if [ -n "$${CI_PIPE}" ]; then \
          //...other docker make stuff
```

My new go test stub has the same external dependencies that is in ${PWD}/../external_vendor and the build process itself is pretty much identical to what's currently being built. Can I do something like this?

```
// Set up other stuff
GO_PROG=        existingTest  newTest/newTest

go: ${GO_PROG}

${GO_PROG}:
    env GOPATH=${PWD}/../external_vendor go build $@.go

docker: 
    @if [ -n "$${CI_PIPE}" ]; then \
          //...other docker make stuff
```

Comment: No, because `go build` works on packages (or directories) and _not_ on files. So your current makefile is broken already.

Comment: Hmm...my new makefile is able to build ("make go") the "existingTest" stub but when it tries to build "newTest/newTest.go", it has trouble because of some undefined methods/variables that are implemented in "util.go". I guess it's because GOPATH is not set up to look in the existingTest directory for util.go. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: The `go` command is designed to work on directories, either building packages/commands consisting of all buildable Go files in a directory or running their [tests](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) (note `foo_test.go` is recognized as a test file but not `fooTest.go`). It sounds like you might be trying to build two executables from different subsets of the files within one package, which it's not designed for. One approach would be take the common part (utils) and move that code out to other package(s), and have your two programs import it.